# ProFTPD - User can't create directory when in a chroot jail

Tags: ftp, chroot, proftpd

I've got a CentOS release 6.5 with Webmin and configured ProFTPd 1.34.

I've put my users in a chroot jail. When they logon they are chrooted to their own home directory.
But there is a problem when users want to create a directory using FTP. When they type `/new_directory` they get Permission denied, but if they type `/home/user/new_directory` directory is successfully created.

In `proftpd.conf` I have:

```
# Cause every FTP user except adm to be chrooted into their home directory
# Aliasing /etc/security/pam_env.conf into the chroot allows pam_env to
# work at session-end time (http://bugzilla.redhat.com/477120)
VRootEngine                     on
DefaultRoot                     ~ !adm
VRootAlias                      etc/security/pam_env.conf /etc/security/pam_env.conf
```

Comment: I checked my configuration on Debian testing, I don't have the VRootEngine nor the VRootAlias directive and it works. I'm not sure you want the VRootAlias directive. Where do you have the permission denied? in a file in /var/log/proftpd/? in the console?

Comment: Thank You. I removed VRootEngine from configuration and now everything is working.